# Is there any solution to double hop (2 different webservers) issue when form-based authentication is used

Tags: asp.net, security

I have two asp.net web applications, webapp_1 on server_1, and webapp_2 on server_2. The users authenticate only on webapp_1 using form based authentication. Later, when the users are redirected to webapp_2, is there any (secure, like when used windows kerberose delegation) way for webapp_2 to know the authentication status of the redirected user.

To achieve this, i think webapp_1 should be able to encrypt and send the session token to webapp_2. I know, this can be worked around by using symmetric keys on both webapps to encrypt the session token. But I do not want to code such approach. Does any framework available that take care of this problem?

Has anyone implemented such solution using Formbased authentication?

Comment: Have you considered [SSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) such as [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID)?

Comment: SSO is an option, like @MarcusAdams suggested.
Another option is to host webapp1 and webapp2 in different sub-domains of the same domain: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx . Also, change the "domain" attribute of the <forms> tag to your domain name, with a leading dot: domain=".mydomain.com"